# How to get count of RSpec examples already tested at runtime?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I get the number of RSpec examples tested at runtime? I am maintaining a large test suite that takes a long time to run and seems to have a memory leak, and want to periodically output various diagnostics during the test run. In my spec_helper, I start a thread as in the code below. I would like to include in those diagnostics the number of tests already run. (The total number of tests to test would be great too, if that is available.)

```
  Thread.new do

    start_time = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)

    classes = [
      SemanticLogger::Logger,
      SemanticLogger::Appender::IO,
      # ...
    ]

    loop do
      STDERR.puts
      classes.each do |klass|
        instance_count = ObjectSpace.each_object(klass).count
        uptime = (Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) - start_time).round(0)
        STDERR.puts format("%5d:  %10d  %s\n", uptime, instance_count, klass)
      end
      STDERR.puts
      sleep 10
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to count the examples explicitly in a `before(:each)` block that applies to all test examples (for example, in a universally included `spec_helper.rb` file). For example:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  $rspec_example_count = 0

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    $rspec_example_count += 1
```

(If you can get by without using a global variable, even better, but the global variable is probably fine given that it is only used in an rspec test suite.)